# Output in pdf format С# iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am just starting to explore itextsharp C# library and have encountered an exception.
The type of this exception is specific from this library.

There is the following code that forms the pdf document:

```
private static void returnPdf(IEnumerable<object> reportItemList)
{
    var suggestedFileName = "Sales_By_Payment_Type_Report" + ".pdf";
    using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 60, 30, 30))
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(suggestedFileName, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        doc.NewPage(); 

        var totalList = reportItemList as IEnumerable<ReportItem>;
        if (totalList != null)
        {
          //filter by 14
          var members = typeof(ReportItem).GetMembers().Where(memb =>memb.MemberType == 
            System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property && memb.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(att => (att as ReportProperty)?.PropertyName != String.Empty).Count() != 0);
          var itemNumber = members.Count();
          if (itemNumber != 0)
          { 
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(itemNumber);
            PdfPCell[] itemArray = new PdfPCell[itemNumber];
            for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.Length - 1; i++)
            {
              var customList = members.ElementAt(i).CustomAttributes.Where(t => t.AttributeType == typeof(ReportProperty)).FirstOrDefault()?.ConstructorArguments;
              if (customList.Count != 0) {
                itemArray[i] = new PdfPCell();
                itemArray[i].Phrase = new Phrase(customList[0].Value.ToString());
              }
            }
            PdfPRow pdfRow = new PdfPRow(itemArray);
            table.Rows.Add(pdfRow);                
            //footer
            table.Rows.Add(new PdfPRow(new PdfPCell[itemNumber]));
            try
            {                      

              **doc.Add(table);**

            }
            catch (DocumentException ex)
            {
              throw ex;

            }           

          }
        }

    }
}
```

In the try block an exception is thrown by a DocumenException from iTextSharp

[image]

doc, table are not nulls
Please help, thank you

```
iTextSharp.text.DocumentException:  reference to an object does not indicate an object instance.
    в PdfTesting.Program.returnPdf(IEnumerable`1 reportItemList) в D:\FranPosTest\iconnect-web\PdfTesting\Program.cs:строка 70   
    в PdfTesting.Program.Main(String[] args) в D:\FranPosTest\iconnect-web\PdfTesting\Program.cs:строка 107
    в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
    в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
    в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
    в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Please provide the exception message in English.

Comment: Please provide the exception message *as text*.  I can't read that.

Comment: The object reference does not indicate an object instance. The type of an exception is - iTextSharp.text.DocumentException

Comment: Why don't you post the output of "ex.ToString()" here?

Comment: Do not use `throw ex;` in the `catch` block. Use `throw;` instead.

Comment: Neither doc nor table are not null

Comment: But all the cells in your "table footer" row are `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this

```
//footer
table.Rows.Add(new PdfPRow(new PdfPCell[itemNumber]));
```

I.e. you create a new `PdfPRow` based on a new `PdfPCell` array you set no value in, so all entries in that array are `null`.

When iText attempts to layout that table during `doc.Add(table)`, it eventually tries to layout this row, too, and stumbles over all those `null` cells.

Comment: Thank you, I am very gratefull